# Change the dynamic text color in a same cell of excel sheet using apache poi?

Tags: excel, dynamic, apache-poi

I am using POI library to deal with an Excel file, what I need is
am dealing with an application in that if you modify anything the changes should be shown in red color.

Example: In my application one of the records has 
 "**stackflowisgood**" and then I modify it with "**stackoverflowisgood**",
now the new change is "over".

So there will be a link available to download an Excel file. After downloading, the Excel should be like "stackoverflowisgood" showing the "over" in red color in the same cell. So here my data changes all the time depends on the user change, so I cannot use any fixed index to color it,
 this code is applicable for specific string

```
HSSFRichTextString richString = new HSSFRichTextString("Hello, World!");
richString.applyFont(6, 10, blueFont);
```

but I need for dynamic string.

Comment: Why not just look up the index of the text to style, then style that?

Comment: It's an random dynamic string, so first need to compare the previous string with the new string and need to get the index for the changes in the new string. Finally the changes in the new string should be colored.

Comment: OK. Show us the code you're using to do that, then we can help with POI bit

Comment: HSSFwb wb= new HSSFwb();
HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("FirstSheet");  
HSSFFont blueFont = wb.createFont();
blueFont.setColor(HSSFColor.BLUE.index);
HSSFCellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
style.setFont(blueFont);
HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((short)0);
rowhead.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue("Name");
HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short)1);
HSSFCell cell = row.createCell((short) 0);
cell.setCellStyle(style);
HSSFRichTextString richString1 = new HSSFRichTextString("sankumarsingh");
richString1.applyFont(3, 8, blueFont);
row.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue(richString1);

Comment: It would look better, and it would be more readable, to add your code by editing your question and formatting it as code rather than adding it as a comment.